# Angular "Unknown Argument: Serve"

Tags: angular-cli

I have cloned an Angular project from DevOps and have had issues setting up.

"ng serve" Results in the following error " Error: Unknown argument: serve"

npm install works

ng version works (see below)

```
Angular CLI: 14.0.1
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
```

Comment: I know this a little old. Could you paste your package.json.
If you found the solution, could you post it?

Comment: Sorry I only saw this now, a colleague got me to install a much older version of CLI & python. Not sure why this was the solution but perhaps it will help someone in the future.